# What is the difference between GetSetMethod and SetMethod on a PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection

So, PropertyInfo has a GetSetMethod method that returns the setter method for this property. It also has a SetMethod property that does the same (as far as I can see).

I'm asking this because it seems that GetSetMethod returns null if the property isn't public while SetMethod still works.

I couldn't find much on MSDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right.

That is from the mscorlib (just used dotPeek):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the public set accessor for this property.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// The MethodInfo object representing the Set method for this property if the set accessor is public, or null if the set accessor is not public.
    /// </returns>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    public MethodInfo GetSetMethod()
    {
      return this.GetSetMethod(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When overridden in a derived class, returns the set accessor for this property.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <returns>
    /// Value Condition A <see cref="T:System.Reflection.MethodInfo"/> object representing the Set method for this property. The set accessor is public.-or- <paramref name="nonPublic"/> is true and the set accessor is non-public. null<paramref name="nonPublic"/> is true, but the property is read-only.-or- <paramref name="nonPublic"/> is false and the set accessor is non-public.-or- There is no set accessor.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="nonPublic">Indicates whether the accessor should be returned if it is non-public. true if a non-public accessor is to be returned; otherwise, false. </param><exception cref="T:System.Security.SecurityException">The requested method is non-public and the caller does not have <see cref="T:System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission"/> to reflect on this non-public method. </exception>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public abstract MethodInfo GetSetMethod(bool nonPublic);

    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public virtual MethodInfo SetMethod
    {
      [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")] get
      {
        return this.GetSetMethod(true);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

They do the same thing, but the property is the new addition: has been added in .NET 4.5, while the `GetSetMethod` has been around since .NET 2.0.

The only difference is that the property will return the setter even if it is non-public, while the method would return only a `public` one. From the documentation:

> Returns the *public* set accessor for this property. [[Method documentation]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ef4d5h3.aspx)

vs.

> Gets the set accessor for this property. [[Property documentation]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setmethod.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`SetMethod` is just a shortcut for `GetSetMethod(true)` (i.e. it returns setter method no matter whether it is public or not). It is implemented this way:

```
public virtual MethodInfo SetMethod
{   
    get
    {
        return this.GetSetMethod(true);
    }
}
```